# I am facing error as Run time 1004 on below filter function in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criterial:="*" & [F1] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a typo `Criterial` should be `Criteria1`

Comment: @SiddharthRout amazing eyes.

Comment: Not actually @BigBen. It took me more than a minute to spot that :( What caught my eyes was the small "f" in `field` so i realized that this code was not directly from VBE.

Comment: Eh - I didn't spot it at all so IMO "amazing" is still accurate.

Comment: amazing it is then @BigBen :D